# Python 3.x: Use index of second repeated index

Tags: python, list, indexing, printing

There are lots of similar posts out there, but I could not find something that directly matched, or resulted in a solution, to the issue I am dealing with.

I want to use the second instance of a repeated index contained in a list as the index of another list. When the function is executed, I want all numbers from the start of the list up to the first asterisk to `print` after User Code, all numbers between the first asterisk and the second asterisk to print after Pass Code, and then all numbers following the second asterisk until the end of the list to print after Pin Code. Example data for digit would be `"['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '*', '6', '*', '7', '8', '9', '10', '1']"` . The number of elements for User Code, Pass Code, and Pin Code can change which is why I am attempting to have it print around the asterisks.

In other words, I want the code below to `print` , assuming those digits exist,  `User Code: 12345, Pass Code: 6, Pin Code: 789101`, all in one line. I do not want the asterisks to `print`.

```
print_string += 'Elapsed Time: ' + str(time) + ', ' + 'User Code: {} '.format(''.join(str(dig) for dig in digit[:digit.index('*')])) + \
                        'Pass Code: {} '.format(''.join(str(dig) for dig in digit[digit.index('*'):digit.index('*')])) + \
                        'Pin Code: {} '.format(''.join(str(dig) for dig in digit[digit.index('*'):]))
print(print_string)
```

I just cannot figure out how make it look for sequential asterisks. If there is a simpler way to execute this, please let me know!

Thanks

Comment: [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)?

Comment: FYI I am new to Python. @spectras Not totally sure how str.split would work in this case. Correct me if I am wrong, but aren't str.split is used to manipulate how strings are stored, and in this case, in lists? If this could be used, I am not sure how to use it. Essentially, I would like to call the first asterisk as the right index for Code1, the first asterisk as the left index and the second asterisk as the right index for Code2, and the second asterisk as the left index for Code3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to combine the use of `split` and `enumerate`.

`split` will turn the values into a list, and you can use
`enumerate` to get the index of the current code while still getting the value.

```
code = '1234*5678*9101'
for i,val in enumerate(code.split('*')):
    if i < len(lst)-1:
        val += "*"
    print ("Code {}: {}".format(i, val))
```

You could also use the `end` parameter of print if you want it all on one line, making the `print look like this:

```
print ("Code {}: {},".format(i, val), end='')
```

Results:

```
Code 1: 1234*
Code 2: 5678*
Code 3: 9101
Code 1: 1234*, Code 2: 5678*, Code 3: 9101,
```

**Edit: Updated with new post information**

Optional printing with titles:

```
codeIn = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '*', '6', '*', '7', '8', '9', '10', '1']

codeVals = ("".join(codeIn)).split("*")

titles = ["User Code", "Pass Code", "Pin Code"]
for title, val in zip(titles, codeVals):
    print ("{}: {}".format(title, val))
```

Output:

```
User Code: 12345
Pass Code: 6
Pin Code: 789101
```

Comment: What would I do if I don't want it to print "code 1" and "code 2" and "code 3" as the outputs? I don't want it to sequentially number "Code { }:" but instead I want it to print "User Code: " "Pass Code: " and "Pin Code: ", all in one line.
@bloominonion

Comment: You could just create another list with the titles to use. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

Split on the asterisk (separator) to get the individual strings.
When you print, append it to all but the last item.

```
in_str = '1234*5678*9101'
sep = '*'
code_list = in_str.split(sep)

for seq, item in enumerate(code_list):
    term = '*' if seq < len(code_list)-1 else ''
    print "Code" + str(seq) + ':', item + term
```

Output:

```
Code0: 1234*
Code1: 5678*
Code2: 9101
```

Comment: And most probably the asterisks in the question were not a requirement but a side effect of how the OP thought about the problem. @drauch> is it ok if the extracted codes do not include the extraneous asterisk? That would make the code even simpler as this answer actually re-adds them manually after splitting the codes.

Comment: @spectras, the asterisks are not a requirement. The extracted codes do not need to include the asterisks, just the values between.

Comment: @Prune I forgot to mention that the data input for digit, or in your case in_str, is actually a list. So the input instead looks like "['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '\*', '6', '*', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11']", which is causing your code provided to result in: `Attribute Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: You presented it as a string, to wit, Example data for digit would be '1234*5678*9101'.`  Please correct your posting.  The trivial way to "fix" this is to `join` the list into a single string, then continue with the solutions we've given you.

Comment: @Prune I have updated the post. Hopefully it is clearer as to what I want to do.

Comment: Yes.  These two answers still give you code you can use to divide the list as desired.  Can you move ahead from here?

Comment: @Prune Still having issues. I am getting errors with both codes. Current error when attempting to run is still `Attribute Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`. I will attempt to resolve, but I am not an experienced programmer so I am having difficulty.

Comment: @Prune Attempting to use `join` to make the list into a string, but now it is printing only as `('Code0:', '')`

Comment: @DRauch: you cannot split a list; only a string.  As I said, you would have to join the list into a string.  For your `('Code0:', '')`, I can't help from output alone ... I have to know what code you're using.  Also, have you applied basic debugging tools to the problem?  Insert `print` statements to trace data and control flow, etc.?  See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.